Proving that $\left| {{a}_{1}^{2} - {a}_{2}}\right| \leq 2, \left| {2{a}_{1}{a}_{2} - {a}_{1}^{3} - {a}_{3}}\right| \leq 2$
Let $f\left( z\right)  = 1 + \mathop{\sum }\limits_{{n = 1}}^{\infty }{a}_{n}{z}^{n}$ be holomorphic in $B\left( {0, 1}\right)$ and  $\operatorname{Re}f\left( z\right)  \geq$ $0, \forall z \in  B\left( {0, 1}\right)$. I have proved that
(1) $\left| {a}_{n}\right|  \leq  2, \forall n \in  N$;
(2) $\frac{1 - \left| z\right| }{1 + \left| z\right| } \leq  \operatorname{Re}f\left( z\right)  \leq  \left| {f\left( z\right) }\right|  \leq  \frac{1 + \left| z\right| }{1 - \left| z\right| }, \forall z \in  B\left( {0, 1}\right)$.
But I have no idea on how to prove
(3) $\left| {{a}_{1}^{2} - {a}_{2}}\right|  \leq  2, \left| {2{a}_{1}{a}_{2} - {a}_{1}^{3} - {a}_{3}}\right|  \leq  2$.
Represent $a_i$ by $f$ through the integral? Can (1),(2) be helpful?

I would look at the positivity of the forms $\sum_k\sum_l a_{k-l}w^k\bar w^l$ where $a_0=2$ and $a_{-k}=\bar a_k, k \ge 1$ which follows from the Herglotz representation; $n=2$ should give the first and $n=3$ second inequality

@Conrad Can you give more hints? consider $\overline{f(z)}f(z)$?

@Conrad From $f$, how can we find one more holomorphic $g$ such that $g(0)=1, \Re g\geq 0$, so the Taylor coefficients are in (3)$?

Try $1/f$ and see its coefficients ($\Re (1/f)$ has same sign as $\Re f$)

Please do not use titles consisting only of math expressions; these are discouraged for technical reasons -- see meta.
